# How to get a list of the values in this Graph object?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, rule

This graph gives the loops of these rules clearly.

```
Graph[Thread[RandomSample[Range[100]] -> RandomSample[Range[100]]], VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

However, graph a side, how might I get the list for each of the loops, such as

```
SeedRandom[10];
loops = Thread[RandomSample[Range[100]] -> RandomSample[Range[100]]]
```

I wish then to get something like ordered list

> { { 81, 52, 16, 55, 41 }, {72, 3, 100, 65} , { ..... }, { .......} }

As an extra, how to get a nicer graph with better vertex labels??

[image]

Comment: The question is not clear to me. Can you answer whether you were looking for weakly connected components?

Comment: In case it was you who downvoted, please clarify the question and explain what you are looking for that my answer does not provide? Furthermore, if another answer does provide what, it is good etiquette to mark it as accepted. It is also good etiquette to respond to requests of clarification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question is not very clear. It sounds like you are looking for [`WeaklyConnectedComponents`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WeaklyConnectedComponents.html). This will give the list of vertices in each of the components visible in your plot.

This approach is not guaranteed to return vertices in the order in which they appear in the cycle. To do that, you can use:

```
sortCycle[g_] := TopologicalSort@EdgeDelete[g, First@EdgeList[g]]
```

```
sortCycle /@ WeaklyConnectedGraphComponents[g]
```

The `sortCycle` function is meant to be applied to a directed cycle graph. It removes an arbitrary edge and sorts the vertices in topological order. To test that its argument is valid, you can use

```
directedCycleGraphQ[g_?DirectedGraphQ] := VertexInDegree[g] == VertexOutDegree[g] && AllTrue[VertexInDegree[g], # == 1 &]
directedCycleGraphQ[_] := False
```

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I was looking for and looks like the most efficient one. Sorry about the late acceptance as I need to use VPN to access this site.

Comment: @CasperYC I just realized that you wanted to vertices in a specific order, and updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 5):

```
SeedRandom[10];
graph = Graph[
  Thread[RandomSample[Range[100]] -> RandomSample[Range[100]]], 
  VertexLabels -> "Name", EdgeStyle -> Red, 
  EdgeShapeFunction -> {{"FilledArrow", "ArrowSize" -> 0.04}}]
```

[image]

- **PermutationCycles**

`ConnectedComponents` can not work, so I consider

```
SeedRandom[10];
relations = 
  Thread[RandomSample[Range[100]] -> RandomSample[Range[100]]];
permutation = Values@Sort@relations
cycles = PermutationCycles[permutation]
cycles[[1]]
(*Reverse[cycles[[1]],2]*)
```

> `{{1, 80, 42, 99, 19, 10, 20, 47, 57, 35, 5, 91, 75, 60, 59, 85, 27,  51, 73, 71, 37, 22, 15, 25, 30, 54, 21, 62, 97, 9, 33, 32, 44, 6,  82, 88, 79, 84, 92, 94, 76, 43, 18, 67, 36, 46, 83}, {2, 49, 34, 45, 31, 96, 29, 50, 14, 66, 53, 4, 11, 64, 7, 77, 93, 13, 40, 58, 39,  24, 63, 86, 87, 95, 28, 78, 68, 98, 90, 89, 70, 8, 56, 17, 48, 12,  38, 61, 69}, {3, 72, 65, 100}, {16, 55, 41, 81, 52}, {23, 26, 74}}`

- **FindCycle**

```
SeedRandom[10];
graph = Graph[
   Thread[RandomSample[Range[100]] -> RandomSample[Range[100]]], 
   VertexLabels -> "Name"];
data = FindCycle[graph, Infinity, All]
data[[;; , ;; , 1]]
```

> `{{23, 26, 74}, {65, 100, 3, 72}, {16, 55, 41, 81, 52}, {86, 87, 95,  28, 78, 68, 98, 90, 89, 70, 8, 56, 17, 48, 12, 38, 61, 69, 2, 49,  34, 45, 31, 96, 29, 50, 14, 66, 53, 4, 11, 64, 7, 77, 93, 13, 40,  58, 39, 24, 63}, {19, 10, 20, 47, 57, 35, 5, 91, 75, 60, 59, 85, 27, 51, 73, 71, 37, 22, 15, 25, 30, 54, 21, 62, 97, 9, 33, 32, 44, 6,  82, 88, 79, 84, 92, 94, 76, 43, 18, 67, 36, 46, 83, 1, 80, 42, 99}}`

Answer (score 5):

Based on `TopologicalSort`, which will takes into account the direction of the edges :

```
SeedRandom[10];
graph=Graph[Thread[RandomSample[Range[100]]->RandomSample[Range[100]]],VertexLabels->"Name"];

TopologicalSort[EdgeDelete[#,First[EdgeList[#]]]]&/@ConnectedGraphComponents[graph]
```

> {{87,95,28,78,68,98,90,89,70,8,56,17,48,12,38,61,69,2,49,34,45,31,96,29,50,14,66,53,4,11,64,7,77,93,13,40,58,39,24,63,86},{10,20,47,57,35,5,91,75,60,59,85,27,51,73,71,37,22,15,25,30,54,21,62,97,9,33,32,44,6,82,88,79,84,92,94,76,43,18,67,36,46,83,1,80,42,99,19},{26,74,23},{55,41,81,52,16},{100,3,72,65}}